# Space between footnote index and text

Tags: footnotes

I think there is not enough space in a footnote between the index (the superscript 1, 2, etc.) and the text (inside `\footnote{...}`). How can I increase the space between the index and the text?

Comment: Recently you asked [another question about spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98463/space-between-two-slashes). I do not think they are invalid questions but the problem might not be the spacing for certain fonts or in certain document classes (which both are often made by typesetting professionals) but simply that you dislike their aesthetics. Maybe trying to find a font or document class that pleases your eyes more would be a better solution? When I started using LaTeX I often thought things looked strange or incorrect because my aesthetic sense was corrupted by inferiror tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the rough scaffold I use to make changes to the footnote format (replace the `1em` by whatever suits you):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
  \long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode%
    \@thefnmark)\hspace{1em}\nobreak
    \relax#1%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Comment: PS: you might consider using proper figures instead of superscript ones in the footnotes. It looks a lot better to most people (me included).