# Space between the two slashes in “http://” too big

Tags: spacing, characters, kerning, sans-serif

I'm using a lot of links with `http://` in my document, but the two slashes are too much separated, I'd like them to be more near each other. How do I do this, in a neat way?

I'm using a sans-serif font: `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`

Comment: I would use the ``url``-command from the ``url`` package: ``\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}``

Comment: That makes a monospace font, I really want the sans-serif font.

Comment: @CamilStaps Use `\urlstyle{sf}`. Also have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98466/how-to-reduce-the-space-between-two-slashes-when-using-url

Comment: @lockstep There’s also `\urlstyle{same}` which picks `\familydefault` and is a tiny bit more comfortable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do what you want. Of course, you can choose the command name (`\twobar`) and the amount of kerning (–0.2em):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\twobar}{/\kern-0.2em/}
\begin{document}
{\sffamily

http://www.jb.com.br

http:\twobar{}www.jb.com.br

}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or `\def\http://{http:/\kern-.2em/}` and `\http://www.x.y` :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Comment: @egreg : Thank you. I'm not very sure about how `\def` works, yet, so I was more comfortable to stay with `\newcommand`

Comment: @BiancaLobo It's just a silly suggestion, based on low level (non LaTeX) features of TeX; but it might be handy.

Comment: @Tobi You sure that was a typo? I always thought `ex` was a *height*

Comment: It doesn’t matter matter. An `ex` is based on the *height* of the small letter x and an `em` is based on the *width* of the capital M, but it is okay to measure a width in multiples of `ex` and heights in multiples of `em`. But on may consider it good style to use `ex` for heights and `em` for widths, so I’ll change my edit to `em`s …