# How to reduce the space between two slashes when using \url?

Tags: spacing, urls, characters, kerning

This is a follow-up question to [Space between the two slashes in “http://” too big](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98463/space-between-two-slashes). Bianca Lobo's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98464/510) (defining a `\twobar` command with proper kerning) is nice; however, it doesn't work in the argument of the `\url` command of the [package](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) of the same name. How can one reduce the space between two slashes when using `\url`? (I'm interested in a solution for sans-serif as well as for roman fonts.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\newcommand{\twobar}{/\kern-0.2em/}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\urlstyle{sf}

http:\twobar www.tex.stackexchange.com

\url{http://www.tex.stackexchange.com}

\url{http:\twobar www.tex.stackexchange.com}

\bigskip

\rmfamily
\urlstyle{rm}

http:\twobar www.tex.stackexchange.com

\url{http://www.tex.stackexchange.com}

\url{http:\twobar www.tex.stackexchange.com}

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `url` package has a way how to do search-and-replace in the url strings. See the self-documented code. We tweak into `\Url@acthash` because it's called by `\url` exactly at the right place.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
% nice "//"
\newcommand{\twobar}{/\kern-0.2em/}
% store original \Url@acthash
\let\orig@Url@acthash\Url@acthash
% make new \Url@acthash that acts "//" as well
\let\new@Url@acthash\Url@acthash
\g@addto@macro{\new@Url@acthash}{\Url@Edit\Url@String{//}{\twobar}}
% make \urlstyle use the original \Url@acthash
\let\orig@urlstyle\urlstyle
\def\urlstyle{\let\Url@acthash\orig@Url@acthash\orig@urlstyle}
% make selected url styles use the new \Url@acthash
\g@addto@macro{\url@rmstyle}{\let\Url@acthash\new@Url@acthash}
\g@addto@macro{\url@sfstyle}{\let\Url@acthash\new@Url@acthash}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\urlstyle{sf}
http:\twobar www.tex.stackexchange.com
\par
\url{http://www.tex.stackexchange.com}
\par
\url{http:\twobar www.tex.stackexchange.com}
\bigskip

\ttfamily
\urlstyle{tt}
http:\twobar www.tex.stackexchange.com
\par
\url{http://www.tex.stackexchange.com}
\par
\url{http:\twobar www.tex.stackexchange.com}
\bigskip

\rmfamily
\urlstyle{rm}
http:\twobar www.tex.stackexchange.com
\par
\url{http://www.tex.stackexchange.com}
\par
\url{http:\twobar www.tex.stackexchange.com}
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! `url` is by D. Arsenau, after all. :)

Comment: That's ... egregious. ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Define a special behavior for the slash:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\makeatletter
\def\Url@twoslashes{\mathchar`\/\@ifnextchar/{\kern-.2em}{}}
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\do\/{\Url@twoslashes}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\urlstyle{sf}\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/4427}

\bigskip

\urlstyle{rm}\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\bigskip

\urlstyle{tt}\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}


\end{document}
```

[image]

A more complex definition that avoids kerning in `tt` style is

```
\def\Url@twoslashes{%
  \mathchar`\/% print a slash
  \expandafter\ifx\UrlFont\ttfamily
    \expandafter\@gobble % do nothing if style is tt
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone % check if a / follows and insert a kern
  \fi
  {\@ifnextchar/{\kern-.2em}{}}
}
```

Not completely foolproof if silly definitions of `\UrlFonts` are made for some new style.

Comment: ``\def\Url@twoslashes{\@ifnextchar/{\mathrlap{\mathchar`\/}\phantom{.}}{\mathchar`\/}}``

Comment: @yo' The original code in that answer worked fine. With your patch, I had to include `\usepackage{mathtools}`, but I still get `Missing number, treated as zero.`. With LNCS class, I could not get your real answer running, but this here works fine. I should provide a MVE for checking though :\.

Comment: Is it possible, that this solution prevents URLs be wrapped at `/`?

Comment: @koppor Quite possible.